# Which one is the correct form of reported speech for the following sentence?

Tags: tense, reported-speech, backshifting

Which one is the correct form of reported speech for the following sentence? why?

"When were you born?", he asked him.

=>

> 1- He asked him when he had been born.
>   2- He asked him when he was born.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version is correct.  The second version sounds fine (to my native ear), probably because being born is not a repeated event, so the grammatical distinction between the time of the event and the time of asking is unambiguous.

- "When did you eat?" he asked him.  => He asked him when he had eaten.
- "When did you get married?" he asked him. => He asked him when he had gotten married. / He asked him when he got married.  (Both sound okay.)